# Efficient way to collate/aggregate specific data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, split, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

I'm looking for an efficient way to gather and aggregate some date in Google Sheets. I've been looking at the query function, pivot tables, and Index + Match formulas, but so far I've not found a way that brings me to the result I'm looking for. I have a set of data which looks more or less as follows.

[image]

The fields with an X represent irrelevant data which I don't want to show up in my end result. They only serve to illustrate that there are columns of data that I don't want in between the columns of data that I do want. The data in those columns is of varying types and of varying values per type, they are not actually fields with an "X" in it. Only the fields with numbers are of interest along with the related names at the top and left of those. The intent is to create a list that looks more or less like this.

[image]

I've highlighted those yellow fields because that data has been aggregated. For example, in the original file field D3 shows a relation between Laura and Pete with the number 1, and field L3 also shows a relation between Laura and Pete, so the number in that field is to be added to the number in the other field resulting in an aggregated total of 2 for that particular combination.

I would really appreciate any suggestions that can help me get to an elegant and efficient solution for this. The only solutions I can come up with would involve multiple "in-between" sheets and there just has to be a better way.

#### UPDATE:

Solved by applying the solution in player0's answer. I just had to switch around the order of Col1 and Col2 in the formula to get the table sorted the way I needed it. Formula looks like below now. Many thanks to both player0 and Erik Tyler for their efforts.

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"×"&D1:N1&"×"&D2:N), "×"), 
 "select Col2,Col1,sum(Col3)
  where Col2 is not null 
    and Col3 is not null
  group by Col2,Col1
  label sum(Col3)''", ))
```

Comment: can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"×"&D1:N1&"×"&D2:N), "×"), 
 "where Col3 is not null and Col2 is not null", ))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"×"&D1:N1&"×"&D2:N), "×"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3)
  where Col3 is not null 
    and Col2 is not null
  group by Col1,Col2
  label sum(Col3)''", ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This almost gives the desired result for the example data, except that the columns of names appear in the opposite order and the results aren't aggregated. The thing is though that the actual data does not consist of fields with "X", they are columns with various data types and various values for each data type. As such, this formula could not be applied to the real data.

Comment: @Rainier answer updated with aggregation

Comment: Thank you! I was able to understand this and apply it to my original data. Only had to switch around Col1 and Col2 in your formula to get them sorted on the right attribute. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Given your current data set (which only appears to extend to Col N), place the following somewhere to the right of Col N:

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(FILTER(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(D2:N)),,D1:N1&"~ "&A2:A&"|"&D2:N),A2:A<>"")),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null"),"|"),"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) ''")&"~ "),,2)),"~ ",0,1))`

It would be better if this were placed in a different sheet from the original data. Supposing that your original data sheet is named Sheet1, place the following version of the above formula into a new sheet:

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(FILTER(IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)))),,Sheet1!D1:1&"~ "&Sheet1!A2:A&"|"&INDIRECT("Sheet1!D2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A2:A))),Sheet1!A2:A<>"")),"Select * WHERE Col1 Is Not Null"),"|"),"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) ''")&"~ "),,2)),"~ ",0,1))`

This separate-sheet approach and formula allows for the original data to extend indefinitely past Col N.

Comment: Wow! That's something. The first formula works and gives exactly the result I was going for. The second formula does not do exactly the same thing however. It does also produce the same data but it added 11 rows on top with additional data like this.

1 - Bob - 2
1 - James - 2
1 - Jim - 2
1 - John - 2
1 - Luke - 2
1 - Mark - 4
1 - Paul - 2
1 - Pete - 2
1 - Richard - 2
1 - Roland - 2
1 - Steve - 4

I'm going to have to have a real close look at exactly what is happening in this formula so I can apply it to the real world data I'm working on. Thanks!

Comment: If your real data is anything other than what you show in your post, yes, there may be unexpected results. It sounds like you have the number 1 somewhere that it is being seen as a viable name; or you have numbers-as-text interspersed through your data unknowingly. We can only write solutions based on what we can see in your post. Since the first formula meets the need, please mark the post as "Best Answer" so as to let the contributor community at large know that the issue has been addressed, and to help future site visitors more easily find this solution.

Comment: Hi Erik. The unexpected results with the second formula were in regard to the test data shown in the post above. The real world data is very similar, but in that there are columns with numbers among the ones that should not be included, so the part of IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(...) in the first formula might not work on it. I'm still working on understanding all the parts of both of the formulas you provided. Rest assured that I will mark the question as answered when I get my head wrapped around this. In the meantime, I prefer to leave the question open, in case someone has additional suggestions.

Comment: Without seeing the actual data (and thus having unseen-unknowns), it wouldn't be efficient to try to guess at suggestions or solutions. If you'd like to share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a sanitized but realistic copy of it), I'll be happy to take a look.